# What should I read next in order to make decent apps? (Knows C, HTML and MySQL)

Tags: html, mysql, c

I am beginner in programming, bit knowledgeable in C, MySQL, HTML (+little CSS, CGI and JS). C is my main language. I was already able to make decent websites with basic functionalities and simple games. But I am missing something.

I can add logic to a designed page with the mentioned languages. But how can I make an app that has the design of HTML and logic of C, but does not need a browser and server (XAAMP) to be viewed?

I want to make a legit app (exe). I know it can be with only C but integrating graphics to it is really hard (unlike HTML w/ CGI & JS).

I hope you get what I mean - what is this **next step in programming** I should learn?

(Btw, I also tried programming in Excel VBA, but I really want to code something that runs without any needed other software)

Thanks!

Comment: You should choose the techniques that are most appropriate for your problem and post conrete issues when you're faced with. This question is opinion-based instead.

Comment: @AdamPorad this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/ Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct answer to your question is dependent upon what you want to do next. You have said in your question that you wish to make apps that do not run in the browser. So from here you have different learning paths depending upon the platform for which you wish to build apps. In general some languages like Java and C# are versatile and can be used on many platforms. Some specific options for you could be:

1. Native iOS or OS X Apps - Objective C
2. Native Android Apps - Java. C/C++ if using the Android NDK.
3. HTML5 Mobile Apps - JavaScript and HTML
4. Native Windows Phone Apps - .Net, C#
5. Apps that run on Arduino - C
6. Apps for Raspberry Pi - Python

I think this is just a small list. There are lots and lots of platforms out there for which you can build apps. The Tech Stack that you need to learn will depend only on the platform that you choose. In my opinion, in order to be a versatile and an adaptive programmer you should add 1 Object Oriented Language like **Java** or **C++**, one scripting language like **Python** and 1 database query language like **SQL** to your arsenal. Once you are comfortable with these languages and their paradigms, you will easily be able to transition to other languages for platforms that do not support these.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are your plans. Depending on what you want to develop, you chose the appropriate language/ framework.

If you want to design standalone "exe"s with complex graphics, you can learn **C#**, **JAVA**, **Phyton** and/or **VBNET**. You can develop using several frameworks like visual studio, java, or even with the "new" **HTML5/CSS3**.

Also, depending on your needs, you can develop standalone apps for mobile using **java**, **C++** or **object-C** (for Android or iOS), or even **HTML5** apps on any of both.

Hope this helps